# Cross-compiling Boost for MIPS platform

Tags: boost, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I have a MIPS-linux based platform

I need to cross-compile boost library for this platform.

I tried to imitate the steps from [cross compile Boost 1.57.0 on ubuntu for arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029867/cross-compile-boost-1-57-0-on-ubuntu-for-arm)

My steps:

```html
1 - Download boost 1.70.0 for Linux 
2 - ./bootstrap.sh
3 - Modify project-config.jam 'using gcc' to -> 'using gcc : mips : mips-img-linux-gnu-g++ ; '
4 - ./bjam install toolset=gcc-mips --prefix=/usr/local/boost
```

The process finishes without errors, but there is not ouput generated in /usr/local/boost

Is this proper way to cross compile boost library for mips?

```html
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 32-bit
    - default architecture     : mips1
error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>qcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <architecture>combined <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    - C++11 mutex              : yes
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_auto_declarations : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_constexpr : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_final : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_mutex : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_tuple : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_lambdas : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_noexcept : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_nullptr : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_rvalue_references : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_template_aliases : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_thread_local : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_variadic_templates : yes
    - has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : no
    - bzip2                    : no
    - lzma                     : no
    - zstd                     : no
    - iconv (libc)             : yes
    - icu                      : no
    - icu (lib64)              : no
    - native-atomic-int32-supported : yes
    - native-syslog-supported  : yes
    - pthread-supports-robust-mutexes : yes
    - gcc visibility           : yes
    - long double support      : yes
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
    - libbacktrace builds      : no
    - addr2line builds         : no
    - WinDbg builds            : no
    - WinDbgCached builds      : no
    - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : no
error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>qcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips1 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>x32 <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <architecture>combined <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no
    - bzip2                    : no
    - lzma                     : no
    - zstd                     : no
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/tools/common.jam:977: in toolset-tag
*** argument error
* rule numbers.less ( n1 n2 )
* called with: ( 4 )
* missing argument n2
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/util/numbers.jam:66:see definition of rule 'numbers.less' being called
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/tools/common.jam:854: in common.format-name
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/boost_install/boost-install.jam:87: in boost-install.generate-cmake-variant-
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:107: in modules.call-in
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/util/indirect.jam:105: in indirect.call
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:902: in execute
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:821: in class@action.actualize
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:332: in actualize-action
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:518: in actualize-no-scanner
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:142: in class@virtual-target.actualize
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:810: in load
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/home/*******/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by adding `abi=aapcs` to the b2 command line.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/Orphis/boost-cmake to solve this.

with CMake options can be easily set.

```
1 - Add boost-cmake as a submodule
2 - add_subdirectory(boost-cmake)   in your main CMake
3 - add the dependency to your target as described in the boost-cmake wiki
```