# cross compiling boost libraries with arm-poky-linux-g++

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

Im trying to build boost with **arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++** but I'm unable to find out a way to install it perfectly can anyone help in providing the step by step guide for resolving this problem

I want to build it using the following configuration:

```
** arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/hon-fsl-better-fb/4.9.11-1.0.0/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi **
```

I have followed these steps to build:
[cross compile Boost 1.57.0 on ubuntu for arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029867/cross-compile-boost-1-57-0-on-ubuntu-for-arm)

These are the errors

> project-config.jam:12: Unescaped special character in argument
>   arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++; project-config.jam:13: syntax error at
>   keyword } /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/tools/gcc.jam:203:
>   in gcc.init from module gcc error: toolset gcc initialization: error:
>   version 'arm' requested but 'g++-arm' not found and version '5.4.0' of
>   default 'g++' does not match error: initialized from
>   /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:44: in
>   toolset.using from module toolset
>   /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:543: in
>   process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
>   /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:610: in
>   load from module build-system
>   /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in
>   import from module modules
>   /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in
>   boost-build from module /home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0/boost-build.jam:17:
>   in module scope from module

Ok its not arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ it is arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++ and user-config.jam is missing,that i have added and executed but further these errors are occuring. there are lot of recursive errors like this.

```
    "arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++"   -pthread -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_TIMER_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/cpu_timer.o" "libs/timer/src/cpu_timer.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/cpu_timer.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_timer.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>auto_timers_construction.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_timer.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/timer/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>auto_timers_construction.o...
...skipped <p/install/lib>libboost_timer.a for lack of /install/lib...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/test/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/test_main.o
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from ./boost/config/workaround.hpp:41,
                 from ./boost/detail/workaround.hpp:8,
                 from ./boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/basic_cstring_fwd.hpp:19,
                 from ./boost/test/utils/basic_cstring/basic_cstring.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/test/detail/global_typedef.hpp:15,
                 from ./boost/test/framework.hpp:17,
                 from ./boost/test/impl/test_main.ipp:17,
                 from libs/test/src/test_main.cpp:13:
./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
my printenv
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AS=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-as
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed
AR=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-ar
OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
TARGET_PREFIX=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-
XDG_SESSION_ID=1305
M4=m4
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
NM=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-nm
OECORE_DISTRO_VERSION=2.5
CPPFLAGS=
SSH_CLIENT=10.77.10.234 56896 22
OLDPWD=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/9
OECORE_SDK_VERSION=2.5.3
GDB=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gdb
USER=ubuntu
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
CXXFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types
CONFIG_SITE=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/site-config-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
CPP=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
PATH=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/sbin:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/bin:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/sbin:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/../x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/bin:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-fslc-linux-musl:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
LD=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-ld  --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
PWD=/home/ubuntu/boost_1_68_0
STRIP=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-strip
LANG=en_IN
OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux
CONFIGURE_FLAGS=--target=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi --build=x86_64-linux --with-libtool-sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
KCFLAGS=--sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
CXX=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
OBJCOPY=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ubuntu
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
OPENSSL_CONF=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
CFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types
LOGNAME=ubuntu
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
SSH_CONNECTION=10.77.10.234 56896 159.99.163.81 22
OECORE_ACLOCAL_OPTS=-I /opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/share/aclocal
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/pkgconfig
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
ARCH=arm
RANLIB=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-
CC=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
OBJDUMP=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-objdump
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Any help is appreciated,Thanks

Comment: You're trying to compile using a Yocto generated SDK, right? Did you source the environment-setup script?

Comment: yes,i do export it the PATH but still its not working

Comment: What command did you run? These are errors from what command? How did you configured the boost build? Please show how can others reproduce the same error.

Comment: @arunkumar, could you post the result of executing `printenv` on the same shell you're trying to compile bison with? Just to check the state of the environment variables exactly before the compilation.

Comment: @danlor i have edited the question again once go through it

Comment: @Kamil Cuk i have edited the question again once go through it

Comment: @arunkumar, could you also add the content of the user-config.jam file?

Comment: @danlor only one line i.e, using gcc : arm : arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++